# SQL Quering - Display Rooms in building

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create the ability to only list the rooms in the the building that the user selects. So if they select Building they only see Rm. 1,2,3. If they select Building 2 they will see rm 1,2,3,4,5.

Table 1 - Locations

```
|location id|Building|room|
|1          |123     | 1  |
|1          |123     | 2  |
|1          |123     | 3  |
|1          |456     | 1  |
|1          |123     | 4  |
|1          |456     | 2  |
```

Table 2 - Storage Area

```
|Storage id|Storage Name|Building|Room|
|  1       |storage rm 1|123     |118
```

Query 1 - Get_Buildings

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Locations.Building
 FROM Locations;
```

This query just selects a distinct building number from the "Building column" in table 1 that is used "Building" column in Table 2.

I need to be able to display room numbers based on what building number i select. Can this be done in the database view or only in a form view? If so can someone point me in the right direction or give me some key words to google that will point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you might want something like this:

```
SELECT locations.room
FROM locations
WHERE (((locations.Building)=123));
```

if in VBA,

```
strSql = "SELECT locations.room " & vbCrLf & _
         "FROM locations " & vbCrLf & _
         "WHERE (((locations.Building)=123));"
```

then convert the string to a recordset

```
Dim rstSQL As Recordset
Set rstSQL = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

then use the recordset as a rowsource in a listbox,

```
me.listbox.rowsource = rstSQL
```

---

However, I'd recommend separating your 1st table into three different ones.
tblLocation, tblBuilding, & tblRooms

then you can utilise proper one-to-many relationships.
1 location can have many buildings, 
1 building can have many rooms.